# how to using for loop to display the output like the link?

Tags: java

How I can display this exactly like output? I can display 1 12 123 1234.

[output](https://gyazo.com/7d2e0adba19767243294fafa9637b8bc/)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int i, j, k;

    for (i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {


        for (j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }


        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Should I using 3 time for loop? Please help. Thanks

Comment: I am not willing to click on the provided link. Please post all relevant information into the question. By the way: Your question is unclear. Please describe the exact problem you have.

Comment: Stack Overflow in not solving homework service.

Comment: not it solving homework.. this is my exploration.. i just need to learn programming what I fail.. Sorry everyone. Thank you also for people helping me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you are trying to learn asking here for the solution is not the way.

Comment: I will try to improve myself to ask question.. sorry all..

Answer (score 1):

Use this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, j;
    for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
      for (j=1; j<=i; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
      }

      System.out.print("-");

      for (int k = 10; k >= i; k--) {
        System.out.print("*");
      }

      System.out.println("\n");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much... I got it.. but I have another question

Comment: Now modify the loop in (1) to have a configurable number of stars " * " and automatically calculated corresponding number of rows.

Comment: Means you want to take a user input?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    for(int i =1;i<6;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<11;j++)
            {
               if(j==i*2-1)
               {
                System.out.print(" _ ");
               }
               else
               System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");

        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much... I got it.. but I have another question

Comment: Now modify the loop in (1) to have a configurable number of stars " * " and automatically calculated corresponding number of rows.